# Avoiding boilerplate code in WPF dialogs

Tags: c#, wpf, boilerplate

I am new to WPF, and my application uses several dialogs. Each of the dialogs currently looks like this:

```
public partial class EditTeamDialog : Window {
  public EditTeamDialog() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (sender, args) => MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
  }

  private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DialogResult = true;
  }
}
```

The `Loaded +=` line and the `Click` method both seem to me so common behavior that I expect them to be provided by WPF. It shouldn’t be necessary for every programmer of a dialog window to write this code.

How can I achieve the same behavior (dialog focuses first element on startup, closes on Enter) with writing less code?

Comment: Is subclassing Window not enough for you? Then, just inherit from the subclassed object.

Comment: No, it is not. A _dialog_ window is such a common concept that it even has its own name. Therefore I expect basic support from the framework. Otherwise the risk is just too big that every programmer will invent his own dialog class which works just a tiny little different from all the others. From a UX standpoint, that’s a nightmare.